# CodeIgniter with encrypted URLs

Tags: codeigniter, url, encryption

I want to use codeigniter framework for my project but I dont want it readable, so i have to encrypt url like:

> http://myproject.com/index.php/indexcontroller/myaction/

into:

> http://myproject.com/as79d8a7sd9a8sd7a98d7a9s8d790akmwmwm97aw

I dont know how to achieve such scenario. How controller and methods will be called and how it will be performed.
Please guide me.

Comment: What are the clients afraid of? This won't necessarily help anything.

Comment: he/she doesnt want anybody to play with url params. Anyway, its not about discussing client. Its about the possibility m seeking for.

Comment: @SalmanKhimani: Sometimes the client needs to be told that what he wants is *wrong*.  There are other ways to prevent a user from messing with the URL.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a job for [URI routing](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)!

Add this to your `config/routes.php`:

```
$route['(:any)'] = "MyController/MyFunc/$1";
```

Now when you go to:

```
http://myproject.com/as79d8a7sd9a8sd7a98d7a9s8d790akmwmwm97aw
```

it will be "redirected" to:

```
http://myproject.com/MyController/MyFunc/as79d8a7sd9a8sd7a98d7a9s8d790akmwmwm97aw
```

From there, you can "decode" the URL, and redirect to where you want to go.

Comment: This method is working... but the issue is when is redirect the URL is again visible, so how can I keep the URL segment same but page will be redirect, so that URL will remain encrypted. hope you got my point.

Answer (score 2):

you can solve this problem by play with:
application/config/routes.php

```
$route['(:any)'] = "controller/myaction/$1";
```

for more information
[URI Routing documination](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)

Comment: `as79d8a7sd9a8sd7a98d7a9s8d790akmwmwm97aw` is not a "static" value.  This value will change for each page visited.

Comment: you can use Wildcards (:any) you can found in documintation