# How to encrypt & decrypt url in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, encryption

I want to encrypt my url in codeigniter. For example

http://example.com/PC/Products/ProductsForm

this my official url i want to encrypt it to something like this

http://example.com/PC/Products/F84gvd32cghjSD

How can i do this?

**Thank You**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CodeIgniter with encrypted URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623374/codeigniter-with-encrypted-urls)

Answer (score 1):

**Encryption** is useful where critical data is being transferred in the URL. I have found a simple and secure encryption class with some changes to make it fit for new users. You can use it in Codeigniter websites as well. Just copy it in application/libraries directory and use it in other libraries' style.

**Link:** http://www.99points.info/2010/06/php-encrypt-decrypt-functions-to-encrypt-url-data/

**OR**

```
$this->load->library('encrypt');//load this library. 
$config['encryption_key'] = "YOUR KEY"; // application/config/config.php
$this->encrypt->encode();//Data encryption and returns it as a string
$this->encrypt->decode();//Decrypts an encoded string.
```

Comment: Can you please show me the controller and view

Comment: @TECHNICALSIDEOFFICIAL. You can see controller and views here https://www.formget.com/codeigniter-encrypt

Comment: This is usefull for codeigniter 3, But it would be helpfull if there is a way out in codeigniter 4

Comment: @JagadishMeghval you can try on Codeigniter 4. if they are not working please let me know

Comment: Thanks @MujahidBhoraniya for replying, its not working for codeigniter 4, hope you provide a solution here, It will be fantastic,
As far as I understand, it feels like we need to use encryption classes, then the base64 encode and finally the urlencoders after that in the decryption its a reverse process but somewhere decryption fails